# Puntero obteniendo la dirección de un puntero doble

Tags: c

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fill(int **, int );

int main()
{
    int *A, c;

    printf("Ingrese las dimensiones\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    A = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
    if (A==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: No se pudo reservar la memoria\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fill(&A, c);

    //free(A);
    return 0;
}

void fill(int **wA, int wc)
{
    int *x, i;

    x = &wA;        //warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
    for (i=0; i<wc; i++){
        scanf("%d", x);
        x++;
    }
}
```

Tengo este código, y lo que quiero hacer es una matriz de una dimensión de tamaño variable (A), me surgen dudas al como mandar a llamar a "A" en esa función (fill), por ahí leí que se debe usar un puntero doble, sin embargo a la hora de llenar la matriz dentro de "fill" por medio de un puntero, me aparece esa warning a la hora de apuntar el puntero a la dirección de A (Más o menos a que entiendo "x" apunta a "A" que apunta a "A" que apunta a la dirección de memoria de tamaño (int)*c bytes).

Y lo más importante es cómo voy a pasar devuelta "A" de "fill" a "main" con los nuevos valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```c
x = &wA;
```

Le estás asignando la dirección de memoria del puntero doble al puntero `x`, luego cuando ejecutes la función `scanf`, le estarías pasando lo que tenga el puntero `x` a la función, esto hará que modifique el contenido del puntero doble y esto no es lo que tu quieres, se supone que el objetivo de la función `fill` es rellenar de datos el arreglo dinámico que habías reservado antes de llamar a la función `fill`.

Hay dos posibles soluciones:

**1.** Asignarle al puntero `x` la dirección base del arreglo dinámico y esto lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```c
x = *wa;
```

El operador de desreferencia (`*`) lo hará es acceder al contenido del puntero que hayas pasado por referencia, es decir, el puntero `A`, en la cual, dará como resultado la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del arreglo (a lo que apunte `A`) y de este modo, podrás pedir datos al usuario para poder rellenar de datos el arreglo.

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```c
void fill(int **wA, int wc)
{
    int *x, i;
    x = *wA;        
    for (i=0; i<wc; i++){
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }
}
```

De esta forma, le estarás pasando a la función `scanf` las direcciones de memoria de cada valor del arreglo y así es como se podrá rellenar de datos el arreglo, de una forma segura sin tener errores en tiempo de ejecución.

**2.** Otra posible solución, es que no uses un puntero doble, sino uno simple.

Ejemplo:

```c
void fill(int *wA, int wc)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<wc; i++){
        scanf("%d", &wA[i]);
    }
}
```

E invocas la función de esta forma:

```c
fill(A, c);
```

Ahora ya no deberías usar el operador  de referencia (`&`), debido a que, no estaremos pasando la dirección de memoria del puntero, sino, la dirección de memoria del primer elemento al que apunte `A`.

Comment: Me parece que en la opción 2 el scanf debería ser a &wA[i]. Un problema del cut&paste supongo

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Jeje gracias por la observación.